# getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/ram/hadoop/driver/DriverCode : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, hadoop

This question is asked several times by people. I gone through all the Q&A but still I didn't resolve my issue with those answers.

I compiled the code using Eclipse with Java 1.6.0.15 in the Windows 10. I took the code in the format of jar file and ran with Java 1.6.0.25 in Ubantu 10 OS.

By that I got the follwing error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/ram/hadoop/driver/DriverCode : Unsupported major.minor version
>   51.0

I verified in hadoop-config.sh it is pointing to Java 1.6.

Why this error is coming while running the code.

I verified in hadoop classpath as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Since you are running in java 1.6 check which version the class com/ram/hadoop/driver/DriverCode file is compiled?

Comment: Yes it is compiled with 1.6